# Data collection for chess opening move analysis

Tags: python

How to get data for doing opening move analysis for chess

Hi, I am very new to data science. I need to do some data visualizations as part of my academics. I am planning to do an analysis of chess opening move and winning rate. I am struggling with data collection part. I have tried lichess and chess.com. But the problem is I don't know how to get required data for this analysis as either these sites give me very large size zip files that failed to unzip in my system or small pgn files which I think too short for analysis. As I don't have much clear idea in this area(If I able to get a set of data, I can process it with python) but don't know how to proceed for data. So please somebody help me with a right step to get data.

Comment: Consider adding the "zip" tag to your question since that seems to be the focus of your question.

Answer (score 1):

**There are several ways to collect data for doing opening move analysis in chess. Here are some options:**

**Record your own games:** One way to collect data is to record your own games and analyze your opening moves. You can use a chess app or software that records your moves automatically, or you can manually record your moves on a chess board or sheet of paper. Make sure to save your games so that you can go back and analyze them later.

**Use online databases:** There are many online databases of chess games that you can use to collect data. Some popular databases include ChessBase, ChessGames.com, and Chess.com. You can search for games by player, opening, or other criteria and download the game data to analyze.

**Conduct a survey:** You can also conduct a survey of chess players to collect data on opening moves. You can create a survey using a tool like SurveyMonkey or Google Forms and distribute it through social media, chess forums, or other channels. Make sure to ask for specific opening moves and analyze the data carefully.

**Use machine learning:** Another option is to use machine learning to analyze large amounts of chess game data. You can use a tool like Python's scikit-learn library to analyze game data and identify patterns and trends in opening moves.

No matter which method you choose, collecting and analyzing data on opening moves can help you improve your chess game and make more informed strategic decisions.